# How to enter characters one by one in to a text field in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to enter characters one by one in to a text field in selenium webdriver? I have used the below code but it's not working

```
getDriver().findElement(By.id("PhoneNumber")).sendKeys(Keys.chord("9876544322"));
```

Can anybody suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: Why don't just pass a string to `sendKeys()`: `getDriver().findElement(By.id("PhoneNumber")).sendKeys("9876544322");`?

Comment: Because some input fields react as users type, e.g. start a search after 3 characters, cancel it if another character is pressed and start a search for 4-character string, etc. The logic can be quite complex.

Answer (score 12):

Here is how I am sending character by character using Selenium Webdriver (in Java). This way in the back-end, I verify at each letter press if the character exists in the input. Normal `element.sendKeys()` is not working well for me 2 out of 5 times - the last letter is missing, I guess something is buggy with Selenium Webdriver, I don't know. Try the code below, it works 100% of the time for me.

```
public void TypeInField(String xpath, String value){
    String val = value; 
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    element.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++){
        char c = val.charAt(i);
        String s = new StringBuilder().append(c).toString();
        element.sendKeys(s);
    }       
}
```

As you see, I get the value needed to be typed and in the `for` loop, I take each character, convert it to string and send it to textbox. Also, I have a search for xpath, you can change that to id, or classname, or whatever you want.

Comment: this solution worked perfectly for me except I have to put 100 millisecond sleep after each of the sendkeys call. Our app makes backend call for each of the character type and gives back search result

Comment: Thanks so much. I used several solutions to one of my automation projects. I tried JavaScript, Jquery etc. all solutions but I got some troubles. This solution is like a human like typing and worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: @vikramvi , yes if there is a delay between app/server, its a good ideea to put a wait on it, if not,there will be chances that will fail. Onur , glad i could help :)

Comment: Great stuff! Helped me with a problem I've been having for several hours. Drove me crazy!

Comment: I would recommend a variable delay between characters - what works with 0ms delay may not work with 100ms delay - or 500ms delay, etc.

Comment: Can't i omit StringBuilder and simply write 
for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++)
       { element.sendKeys(val.charAt(i).toString()); Thread.Sleep(100);}

Answer (score 10):

If you want to make your sendKeys more human like, I've used something like this:

```
private static void sendHumanKeys(WebElement element, String text) {
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((int)(r.nextGaussian() * 15 + 100));
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        String s = new StringBuilder().append(text.charAt(i)).toString();
        element.sendKeys(s);
    }
}
```

It sends the keys with a 100ms delay, but only an average of 100ms. It creates a normal distribution with average 100ms and std. deviation 15ms.

Comment: Beautiful!  Worked perfectly for me.  I loved the nextGaussian!  A nice touch.
People are random, and computers are precise.  LOL! :-)

Answer (score 5):

`sendKeys()` does enter characters in sequence, but it can at times run quickly enough to be perceived as a copy/paste action. Though, it is in fact intended to simulate a user entering text by typing. Per the `sendKeys()` JavaDoc:

> /** Use this method to simulate typing into an element, which may set its value. */

If you wanted to slow it down, you could make a method that accepts WebElement and String args, convert the String to `charsequence[]`, then use a for loop and enter each index of the array in the .sendKeys() followed by a `Thread.sleep()`. This seems horribly inefficient, though, as `sendKeys()` recognizes Strings as `charsequence[]` (String *is* a `charsequence[]` in Java). Adding the `Thread.sleep()` will only slow your test needlessly.

Honestly, `sendKeys()` fits your described needs. It's the best way to simulate a user at a keyboard, it just does it really fast.

Comment: "...it just does it really fast" - That's precisely the problem. Some JavaScript does not have time to react - or it does not react as it would for a real user. If an input has logic related to individual characters, you have to create tests that are as close to real human behavior as possible - and "pasting" / rapidly typing an entire string is only one of possible use cases.

Comment: String is a CharSequence, not a CharSequence[].

Comment: Just like Andrei Volgin said, sendKeys is sometimes too fast for a web page; especially if it is going back to the server to search for possible completions.

Answer (score 3):

.chord() will press all keys simultaneously.  Not very well suited for field input.

The .sendKeys() method will accept a String.  Simply pass your input as such and have a go with it.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("element")).sendKeys("Field Input Text");
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("element")).sendKeys("Field Input Text");

sendKeys("Field Input Text") --> It will directly drop the text in the text field. I want a solution where we can enter characters one be one like the way we are typing.

Comment: sendKeys does simulate user keyboard input, typing a string out character by character

Answer (score 3):

I created a Python function of the Java Selenium code.
Find attached below and tweak based on the elements you want to use:

```
def TypeInField(xpath, myValue):
    val = myValue
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    c = ""
    for i in range(0, len(val)):
      c += val[i]
      elem.send_keys(c)
      time.sleep(3)
    elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this function in my test when I want to type a string letter by letter.

```
public void typeOnLetterByLetter(WebElement webElement, String value, long waitBetweenLetters, ChronoUnit unitTime) {
    clear(webElement);
    Arrays.asList(value.toCharArray()).forEach(letter -> {
        typeOn(webElement, String.valueOf(letter));
        pause(waitBetweenLetters, unitTime);
    });
}

private void pause(long time, ChronoUnit unitTime) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(Duration.of(time, unitTime).toMillis());
    } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not defined clear or typeOn like you did pause.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it in C#

```
    public void TypeInFieldCharByChar(IWebElement element,string text)
    {
        var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            strBuilder.Append(text[i]);
            element.SendKeys(strBuilder.ToString());
            strBuilder.Clear();
        }
    }
```