# Unable to enter chars in the textfield using selenium sendKeys

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying enter characters into text field, however its not working. Below I mentioned 2 pieces of code. JS is not working at all. Where as in the first piece of code click is working but not other steps. Xpath is correct as click is working on that.

```
    util.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='input-1']")).click();
    util.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='input-1']")).clear();
    util.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='input-1']")).sendKeys("hjgfjg");
```

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) util.driver;

js.executeScript("document.getElementByXpath('//input[@id='input-1']').value = 'TEST')");
```

[image]

Comment: post the markup and any scripts that run on that form.   Sometimes it can be an overly complicated script that isn't keeping up with the typing.  (Slowing down the typing can help if that's the case...)

Comment: Provided element html. BTW I tried to wait 5 seconds before and after entering one char and still I do not see its entering.

Comment: try without the click or the clear... neither should be needed.

Comment: Same issue with out that as well.

Comment: post the full markup... could be an iframe or the lack of a WebDriverWait or something like that.  Are you seeing any exceptions?

Comment: Can you type some text in textfield manually and post html code ?

Comment: Are you getting an error, and if so what is it?

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to invoke `sendKeys()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.slds-input[id^='input-'][aria-describedby^='help-message-']"))).sendKeys("hjgfjg");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='slds-input' and starts-with(@id, 'input-')][starts-with(@aria-describedby, 'help-message-')]"))).sendKeys("hjgfjg");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `Actions`:

```
WebElement input = util.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='input-1']"));
Actions action = new Actions(util.driver);
action.moveToElement(input).click().sendKeys("test").build().perform();
```

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try below workarounds:

1. Try clicking on the textbox first and then call sendKeys().
2. Angular can't process input events when they arrive too fast.
   As a workaround, you would need to send single characters with a small delay between each.

[Selenium sendKeys are not sending all characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200048/selenium-sendkeys-are-not-sending-all-characters?rq=1)

3. You can try using Actions class.